# Android Application Reverse Engineering BLE ScanSettings/AdvertiseSettings

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I have been working on a reverse engineering project for a particular android application and I have come across some interesting methods which I can not find any documentation for.
This application uses the Android Bluetooth Low Energy API which involves setting up some ScanSettings and AdvertiseSettings.

For example, when the application makes it's AdvertiseSettings object it uses the AdvertiseSettings.Builder as so:

```
AdvertiseSettings.Builder().setAdvertiseMode(100).semSetCustomAdvertiseInterval(i).setConnectable(true).setTxPowerLevel(3).build()
```

The part I do not understand and have not been able to find any information on is the

```
setAdvertiseMode(100)
```

and

```
semSetCustomAdvertiseInterval(i)
```

From the android documentation, the

```
setAdvertiseMode
```

method should take one of three options:

ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER = 0, ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED = 1, or ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY = 2.

As well as this, the

```
semSetCustomAdvertiseInterval
```

method does not seem to exist in the android documentation or any where I can find.

A similar thing happens when the

```
ScanSettings
```

are made using

```
ScanSettings.Builder
```

It uses:

```
builder.setScanMode(100)
```

and

```
builder.semSetCustomScanParams(i1, i2)
```

If I try and make a ScanSetting or AdvertiseSetting that is set to mode 100 or make a call to one of the semSet methods within my own application, I just receive errors.

So I am wondering if anyone has any idea or can enlighten me on what may be happening here?